# Change the user defaults back to the original defaults in UNIX

Tags: unix

I changed the default of users with `useradd –D –b /home/packers –s /bin/bash –g packers` this command.

But I want to change them to original default. Which command do I need to use?

Comment: now all user which will created has base directory "/home/packers". but i want to change that default

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to reset the default configuration to what it was before you entered that command.

Try this to reset the defaults you changed:
`useradd -D -b /home -g users`

Usually you shouldn't change the defaults (-D) unless you have a good reason too. Also, if you want an interactive way of adding users, try `adduser`

Here is all the default values incase you need them: ( it says 100 for group, that is the ID for users )

`GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no`